Question On How To Eliminate An Error When Accessing A JSON File
A JSON file was downloaded through filezilla to a Windows laptop and the file security settings were modified to grant full control to Everyone. Suggestions on how to eliminate the following error when I attempt to print the first 20 lines while running Power Shell as an Administrator will be appreciated:
Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\Users\jbill\Search_App\Data\trial_1.json' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content trial_1.json -Head 20 2> errors.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\jbill\...trial_1.json:String) [Get-Content], Unauthorized 
   AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

I modified the file security to grant full control to Everyone and ran Power Shell as an Administrator. I also applied the Unblock-File command to the file and still get the following error response:
Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\Users\jbill\Search_App\Data\trial_1.json' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content trial_1.json -Head 20 2> errors.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\jbill\...trial_1.json:String) [Get-Content], Unauthorized 
   AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand


It's not a PowerShell issue when you don't have access to the file. Did you check if you access to the file? Since it is downloaded - did you unblock it?  Try Unblock-File

I applied the Unblock-File command while running Power Shell as Administrator, however, the same error message cited above is returned. Any additional suggestions will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Did you check if you have access to the file? Is that all the code?

I am able to open the file in VS Code now, whereas I could not earlier.  I am no going to be troubled by not being able to print the first 20 lines in Power Shell.  Thank you for all the help!

What? ‍♂️
